# Ruby one time assignment on instance variable

Tags: ruby

I usually use "one time assignment" (don't really know how to call this anw) in ruby like this:

```
class FooBar
    def foo
       @foo ||= begin
           # Costly operation putting here
       end 
    end
end
```

This will allow the variable `@foo` to be computed only once, then being used directly in subsequent calls to method `foo`. My question are:

1. Is using `begin`/`end` block in this case good or not, as the documentation states that it is used for encapsulating exceptions, doesn't mention any other uses.
2. Can I use other block types (Proc, Lambda, `do`/`end`) with this syntax? If yes then how?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: That's normally done in `initialize`, but could be done anywhere.  Yes, `@foo` could point to the result of any type of operation: `@foo = arr.map...`, `@foo = if..else...end`, `@foo = lambda...`, etc.

Comment: Please don't change your code once comments or answers have been given, as it can render the latter meaningless.  It's better to leave it as is and add a note (as an edit, not a comment) explaining what you intended, preferably with the word "edit", e.g., "Edit:...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I haven't seen any usage of `begin/end` in the memorization, but I think that's fine.
2. Of course, you can use `lambda` like this `@foo ||= lambda { "foo" }.call`, just remember that the *one time assignment*(`||=`) only evaluate the proc when `@foo` is evaluated to `false`. It's equivalent to the following:

   ```
   if @foo
     @foo
   else
     @foo = lambda { "foo" }.call
   end
   ```

Comment: But doesn't that mean I have to use `@foo.call` to get the value of `@foo`?

Comment: I see. So I can do thing like this also: `Proc.new {}.call`

Answer (score 1):

I typically do it something like this:

```
class MyClass

  def foo
    @foo ||= build_foo
  end

  private

  def build_foo
    puts "I'm expensive"
    5
  end

end
```

I don't see why you'd need to make it any more complicated.  To my eyes having a method named something like `build_XXX` or `process_XXX` clearly explains it's doing something more involved, and having the memoization take place in the publicly-accessible method makes it clear you are avoiding doing that more than once if needed.

Comment: We don't know if herophuong is calling `foo` more than once.  It could be called just once (as with `initialize`) then other methods are called that use `@foo`.